# ¿Doble complemento directo?

Tags: gramática, objetos-directos

¿Cuál es la resolución o las resoluciones al análisis de la siguiente oración?

> Consideramos a Pedro un buen maestro.

Claramente no hay Complemento u Objeto Indirecto porque los dos aceptan migraciones a voz pasiva. Sin embargo me quedan mis dudas sobre aceptar la definición de doble complemento directo. ¿Alguien tiene algún análisis diferente?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"a Pedro" es el **complemento directo**.

En [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_directo#El_complemento_directo_en_espa.C3.B1ol) puedes leer:

> "El complemento directo en español siempre se puede sustituir por lo, la, los, las:"

Por lo tanto, la única opción sería "Lo consideramos un buen maestro". Si intentas sustituir "un buen maestro" por alguna de las partículas citadas anteriormente verás como no tiene mucho sentido.

Otra nota de la misma página nos indica:

> "Al transformar la oración activa en pasiva, el complemento directo se convierte en el sujeto paciente"

La frase "Pedro es considerado (por nosotros) un buen maestro." es correcta, mientras que si intentas convertir "un buen maestro" en sujeto paciente, la frase vuelve a no tener demasiado sentido.

EDIT

¿Qué tipo de complemento sería?

Recurriendo nuevamente a [wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_predicativo), esta vez en la última línea de un artículo que creía de relevancia, he encontrado esto:

> El complemento predicativo aparece también con los verbos semicopulativos que forman predicados mixtos en frases semipredicativas: «Pedro se volvió tonto». Casi siempre suele ser un adjetivo, pero algunas veces (con verbos que signifiquen "nombrar" o "elegir" y "reputar" o "**considerar**") puede ser un sustantivo y puede ir precedido de como: «Eligieron presidente a Pedro». «Eligieron como presidente a Pedro». «**Consideraba a Pedro su mejor amiga**»

Por lo tanto, creo que "un buen maestro" es un **complemento predicativo**.

Comment: Pues para mi no pierde el sentido. Incluso la voz pasiva me suena aun mejor: "Un buen maestro es considerado Pedro por nosotros". Pero suponiendo que efectivamente no es un OD (que es lo que queremos demostrar), que seria? +1 por el approach, no quiero con este comentario decir que tu respuesta esta mal, sino justamente debatir el tema porque es la duda que tengo! :)

Comment: La frase que acabas de poner como ejemplo no me suena demasiado bien pero no he podido encontrar nada para respaldar esta opinion. La frase que me viene a la cabeza es "Un buen maestro es considerado aquel que...". Respecto a la segunda pregunta, ahora edito la respuesta principal.

Comment: Si, entiendo, no es mal approach. Para mi ese complemento se llama "Predicativo Objetivo". Me cuadra perfectamente porque debe concordar en genero y numero con el OD, pero por esta ambiguedad podemos decir lo siguiente? Ej: "Lo (Pedro) consideraba como mi mejor amigo. En verdad lo (tu mejor amigo) consideraba a Pedro" ? Ahora tengo una duda mas, si ese ultimo "lo" responde a una repeticion de Pedro o "mi amigo". Muy bueno.

Comment: Voy a buscar un par mas de ejemplos y a romperme la cabeza tratando de destruir tu approach, no por maldad, sino porque es un buen metodo para encontrar excepciones o bien otra respuesta o idea). Si no lo encuentro la doy por respondida, obviamente. Creo que voy a ir por el camino de la voz pasiva.

Comment: Por mi perfecto, me parece una buena técnica para aprender. El único problema que le veo es hacerlo a traves de los comentarios o esta página en sí. Se supone que es una página de Preguntas/respuestas, no de diálogo, como expresa el [faq](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) (esa parte está en inglés). Si quieres aclarar algo o añadir un contraejemplo, por favor hazlo en la pregunta principal para que también le sirva a otros sin leer los comentarios.

Answer (score -1):

CD: "A Pedro" (sujeto de pasiva)
Complemento predicativo: "Un buen maestro" (referido a CD, concuerdan)

Answer (score -1):

*Consideramos a Pedro un buen maestro*. Esta es la frase

Si pasamos a voz pasiva, o.d.(1) ser màs verbo en p.p.(2), s. Activo (3)

Esa es la fórmula para voz pasiva. Entonces la oración quedaría así:

> Pedro un buen maestro, es considerado por nosotros.

Considerar esta conjugado en nosotros ese es el verbo que pasaría a p.p. Y 
el agente activo no se ve pero es *nosotros*. Por eso lo agregamos al final de la voz pasiva y no puede tener doble complemento porque un buen. Maestro es el adjetivo, escripsion de Pedro.

Referencia de la voz pasiva: 
http://roble.pntic.mec.es/acid0002/index_archivos/Gramatica/voz_pasiva.htm

Comment: Bienvenida a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo revisar la sección [answer]. Por favor, procura responder clara y realmente a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. Tal como está ahora, cuesta mucho de leer y no me queda claro qué estás explicando sobre el doble complemento directo. Sería posible que editases la respuesta un poco, no solo para explicar un poco mejor si no para cuidar también el formato y la ortografía?